# how to avoid large data in login api

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, spring-security, tomcat8

We are using tomcat 8,spring security 4.x and have exposed a /login api via POST, which will authenticate user's credentials. As /login API is typically unsecured, I am afraid, it is possible to do following attacks with our current implementation:

1. Send large input in username and password field. Spring security's UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter simply copies the username and password parameters from servlet into a string. It is possible to submit copious amount of data and causing denial of attack by memory exhaustion. It is possible to use readlistener with servlet 3.1 spec, but if i can avoid making the servlet async, that would be preferred. So, is it possible to simply look at content-size header? The POST for /login will typically have username parameter, it's value (the upper size is bounded), password parameter and its value(size bounded by business rules). So in theory, if i check that content size > certain configurable size, i can deny authentication. Is there any loophole with this approach?
2. An attacker can set content-size header to a large amount and only post small data. In this case, as tomcat simulates reading http body as simulated blocking, a thread could be blocked for long time. Is there a way to specify timeouts in tomcat when tomcat tries to read a http body?

Answer (score 0):

1. Limit the maximum size of the request. You can limit the total headers for requests (`<Connector>`'s `maxHttpHeaderSize` attribute) that will be honored and you can limit the total length of a POST body that is accepted (`<Connector>`'s `maxPostSize` attribute).
2. This attack is called [slowloris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_%28software%29). The "simulated blocking" that Tomcat's NIO actually frees-up threads to avoid a DOS from such an attack. There are timeouts that you can specify to help alleviate the problem of slowloris. I'll leave that as an exercise for you to read the [Tomcat connector documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html) since you obviously haven't yet read it.
3. Why would you leave your `/login` "API" "unsecured"? Secure that bad boy!